# C++: Calling a base class constructor with a computed argument

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

This simple example demonstrates the C++ syntax for calling base class constructors - as far as I understand it as a C++ learner:

```
class BaseClass {
protected:
  int i;
public:
  BaseClass(int x) { 
     i = x; 
  }
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass {
  int j;
public:
  DerivedClass(int x, int y): BaseClass(y) { 
     j = x; 
  }
```

Here, the base class constructor can take named arguments to the derived class constructor as input.

Now, what if I want to call `BaseClass()` constructor with an input value that is not a direct input to `DerivedClass()`? Basically, I'd like to do some multiline work with `x` and `y` within `DerivedClass()`, then pass a calculated value to `BaseClass()`. Can this be done with constructors? Should this be done with some kind of initializer method instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that, yes:

```
class BaseClass
{
  public:
    BaseClass(int x) : i(x) {}

  private:
    int i;
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
  public:
    DerivedClass(int x, int y):
      BaseClass(compute(x, y)), // Neither i or j are initialized here yet
      j(x)
      {}

  private:
    static int compute(int a, int b) { return a + b; } // Or whatever
    int j;
};
```

Note that you can even make `compute()` a non-static method but be aware that `DerivedClass` or `BaseClass` members **won't** be initialized at the time of the call. So you won't be able to rely on their values.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Thanks for the missing `;` fix :D I guess I've been doing too much Python lately.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++11 or newer you can also use lambda expressions:

```
class BaseClass
{
  public:
    BaseClass(int x) : i(x) {}

  private:
    int i;
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
  public:
      DerivedClass(int x, int y): BaseClass(
          [=]()->int
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
                {
                    sum += y + i * x;
                }
                return sum;
            }()), j(x)
      {}

  private:
    int j;
};
```

Comment: +1 for the reminder that there exists lambda. But it will not be good if the computation is too big. It makes difficult to read the constructor (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

Then you can do this:

```
DerivedClass(int x, int y): BaseClass(compute(x,y)), j(y) { 
     //j = x;  //use member-initialization-list ---> ^^^^
  }

int compute(int x, int y) 
{
     //your code
}
```